# background-position align large background-image bottom to bottom of smaller container

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have a large background image that I want to use in a hero element in a site banner.

The bottom of this photo is the crucial part, so I always want it showing. `background-position` will align a smaller photo to the bottom of a larger element, but when the background photo is larger than the element, it keeps the top of the background-image aligned with the top of the container. I want to keep the bottom of the background-image aligned with the bottom of the container.

An example: [here's a background image](http://pixelgirlpresents.com/files/desktops/2013_September_2560x1440_calendar.jpg); I want to  make sure the bottom (some mountains) always show up in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ8vg/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `background-attachment: fixed;` from your hero class.

Comment: Hmm, that **does** make it align correctly, but I really like the fixed image. Any way I can have both? • I'm confused about how the position of the photo is being calculated when it is fixed. Why would that change it so drastically?

Comment: When the background attachment is fixed, it's fixed to the viewport...meaning you can scroll all you want, but the image is not moving. Additionally, its position is set to left bottom, so its bottom-left corner will stay fixed to the bottom-left corner of the viewport. Once removed, the background attachment goes back to its default state of 'scroll' instead of 'fixed'. In 'scroll' mode, it stays fixed relative to its container—in this case the horizontal window through which it is viewed. If that window moves around, so does the background image contained within it.

Comment: As far as having it both ways is concerned, you can have multiple background images, and can achieve some cool effects with positioning, opacity, and whatnot. Checkout this link on MDN:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds